# Connect to Cloud Storage through kubernetes pod with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, google-kubernetes-engine

what I want to achieve, is that for my pods that live inside `GKE` to share files. So what I'm thinking is using the `GoogleCloudStorage` to write and read the files.

I have created a service account in my `kubetcl`

> kubectl create serviceaccount myxxx-svc-account --namespace
> myxxx

Then I also created the service account in my GCP console

Then, I added the roles of `roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser` in my GCP account

Next, I annotated my kubectl account with my GCP service account

> kubectl annotate serviceaccount --namespace myxxx
> myxxx-svc-account
> iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=myxxx-svc-account@myxxx-xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com

I also added the roles of `Storage Admin` and `Storage Object Admin` in the GCP - IAM page

Then, in my `deployment.yaml`, I included my service account

```
spec:
  serviceAccountName: myxxx-account
```

Bellow is how I try to upload a file to the storage

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket('bucket-name');

const options = {
    destination: '/folder1/folder2/123456789'
  };
  bucket.upload("./index.js", options, function(uploadError, file, apiResponse) {
    console.log(uploadError.message)
    console.log(uploadError.stack)
  });
```

I deploy my node application to the `GKE` pods through `docker`. In the dockerFile, im using

```
FROM node
...
...
...
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

But I always get unauthorized 403 error

> Could not refresh access token: A Forbidden error was returned while
> attempting to retrieve an access token for the Compute Engine built-in
> service account. This may be because the Compute Engine instance does
> not have the correct permission scopes specified: Could not refresh
> access token: Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with
> status code 403
>
> Error: Could not refresh access token: A Forbidden
> error was returned while attempting to retrieve an access token for
> the Compute Engine built-in service account. This may be because the
> Compute Engine instance does not have the correct permission scopes
> specified: Could not refresh access token: Unsuccessful response
> status code. Request failed with status code 403
>
> ```
> at Gaxios._request (/opt/app/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:130:23)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async metadataAccessor (/opt/app/node_modules/gcp-metadata/build/src/index.js:68:21)
> at async Compute.refreshTokenNoCache (/opt/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/computeclient.js:54:20)
> at async Compute.getRequestMetadataAsync (/opt/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:298:17)
> at async Compute.requestAsync (/opt/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:371:23)
> at async Upload.makeRequest (/opt/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/resumable-upload.js:574:21)
> at async retry.retries (/opt/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/resumable-upload.js:306:29)
> at async Upload.createURIAsync (/opt/app/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/resumable-upload.js:303:21)
> ```

What I'm doing wrong? seems like I have given the permission already? how can I troubleshoot it? Is it related with the docker image?

Comment: Are you using GKE?

Comment: yes i'm using GKE. so the pod is inside the GKE. and I want it to connect to my Google Cloud Storage